# Unable to RDP to azure instance - Local Security Authority cannot be contacted

Tags: azure

Whenever I try to login to my azure instance via RDP I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried, rebooting, resetting the RDP settings in the console (configure remote desktop - set expiry for future, etc) and I have also tried logging in with my local admin account (as per the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909073/746754) and [here](http://blog.mnewton.com/articles/Solution-RDP-The-Local-Security-Authority-cannot-be-contacted/)) and neither have helped. Before I do something more drastic like try to reset my admin password through powershell or install vnc, I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions. I don't have Azure technical support, so I am not sure if the Microsoft billing support will be much help.

Note: This is a cloud service VM.

Comment: If this is a Cloud Services VM then go to Azure Portal for the service, configure-> remote-> set _expires on_ to a future date.

Comment: @Raf: thanks for the suggestion. I have already tried that (updated my question).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Azure Portal for the service, Configure-> Remote-> set *expires on* to a future date. In certificate field select *Create a new certificate*.

Otherwise untick *Enable Remote Desktop* and apply -> wait until done -> Enable again and that should do it.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you, you put me on the right track. When I went to the Certificate tab on the top panel, I saw that there were a bunch of expired "CN=Windows Azure Tools" certificates that I deleted (RDP must have been using one of these). After this it worked perfectly.

Comment: I am still facing this issue at my Azure VM  however my certificate will be expired on 3/8/2023. Any advice !

Answer (score 11):

I've the same problem when I try connect with RDP to AWS or Azure.

But, I fix the problem when I disabled Anti-virus Bitdefender free.

Verify if you have a Anti-Virus, Proxy, Firewall.

Comment: Suggestions to disable security features should be carefully worded to explain the impact of doing so. How will turning off anti-virus solve an error that is about an expired password?

Comment: Jason, the message wasn't correct. Really, I only stopped my anti-virus. I didn't  do nothing more.

Comment: Holy ****, I can't believe that worked. BitDefender, whaddya doooooin'?

Comment: Wow, this worked for me too! Disabled bitdefender on my local machine. Thanks!

Comment: Wasted hours trying to figure this out!!  Bye-bye Ditfender

Comment: Wasted hours of support and Azure fee due to this. Disabled BitDefender free and i could instantly connect to the VM

Comment: I wasted time trying to resolve and finally, I got a solution due to this post. BitDefender was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case same error message occured when logging in with the (only) local admin user on a VM (not azure, but a VM on a Hyper-V). No option to log in to the system directly.

Luckily there was a service running on the machine which allowed me to execute commands on the console (in my case it was a Jenkins build server, with its Groovy command shell).

Here I executed a groovy script to create a new admin user, what worked perfect for me:

```
"cmd /c net user Administrator \"password\"".execute().text
"cmd /c net user Administrator /active".execute().text
```